# Why is "hanged for this" correct but not "hung"?

Tags: word-usage, tense

In one episode of the TV show [Sherlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherlock_(TV_series)), Holmes and a prisoner has a conversation where Holmes corrected him grammatically many times. The following is just part of that.

> Prisoner: (annoyed) Did it! STABBED HER! Over, and over, and over, and
> I looked down and she weren't… (Sherlock just sighs) …wasn't… moving
> no more… (Sherlock rolls his eyes) …anymore. (calmer) God help me, I
> don't know how it happened, it was an accident, I swear! (Sherlock
> gets up to leave) Hey, you gotta help me, Mr. Holmes! Everyone says
> you're the best. Without you… I'll get **hung** for this.

> Sherlock: No,
> no, Mr. Bewick, not at all. (beat) **Hanged**, yes.

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/hang), both "hung" and "hanged" could be the participle form of "hang"

[image]

Why Sherlock insists "hanged" there?

Comment: Using "hung" to mean "executed by hanging" is similar to using "literally" to mean "figuratively"—a recent change that Holmes and I curmudgeonlyly object to.

Comment: You can use 'hung' for future hangings:  The traitors will be hung at dawn.  But almost the only time you'll see 'hung' for the past is as part of: 'hung, drawn & quartered'.  This is the only example in your cambridge link that isn't 'hanged'.

Comment: "Humans are hanged, horses are hung"

Comment: [Hung](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hung#Adjective) has adjective meanings that are not shared by ‘hanged’ (including a slightly vulgar one, to which Oliver is [referring](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Thesaurus:macrophallic)).  — I suspect ‘hanged’ is preferred in other cases to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @Oliver As famously used in [Blackadder the Third](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0526721/characters/nm0394998).

Comment: Isn't the show named *Sherlock*, not *Holmes*?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Although this is more a matter of style than definition, the stylistic convention is that you always use ***hung*** unless you are describing a person (or I suppose animal) who has been killed by hanging—in which case it should be ***hanged***.

---

This is what Merriam-Webster says about it in ["Is it 'Hung' or 'Hanged'?"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/hung-or-hanged):

> The standard rule for the past tense of *hang* is this: in almost all situations, you should use the word *hung*.
>
> *I **hung** a picture of Noah Webster on the wall.*
> *After school, she **hung** out in the library.*
>
> Use *hanged* when referring to a person being suspended by a rope around the neck until dead.
>
> *The Salem "witches" were not burned; they were **hanged**.*
> *Justice Wargrave ordered Edward Seton to be **hanged** by the neck until dead.*
>
> It's not that simple, however: most usage guides reserve *hanged* for people subjected to death, which means if an inanimate object is suspended from a gallows, the correct term is *hung*.
>
> *Despised by the voters, he was **hung** in effigy.*

---

To further illustrate this point, I wrote a short piece of fiction a while ago (I will emphasize the words):

> The paintings of **hanged** corpses all **hung** in the gallery. As the exhibit was also a piece of performance art, the artist had put a noose around his neck and **hung** himself on the wall as well. Unfortunately, a spectator noticed that he was no longer breathing. When the police were called, they had no choice but to file a report about the man who’d both **hung** himself on purpose and **hanged** himself by mistake.

Comment: There's an analogous distinction between "lay" and "lie;" and between "sit" and "set." I believe it's only stylistic insomuch as native speakers are confused about the finer points of grammar. However, I'm not sure of the rule myself!

Comment: @jpaugh Not the same distinction; lay/laid/laid and set/set/set are _usually_ transitive, while lie/lay/lain (in the sense of reclining, not in the sense of telling falsehoods) and sit/sat/sat are _usually_ intransitive. With "hang," we are talking about the difference between transitive with inanimate object and transitive with animate object, not the difference between hang (v.t.) and hang (v.i.).

Comment: This distinction is, incidentally, a key point in [another](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1612329802/ref=bseries_primary_0_1612329802) murder mystery.

Comment: How about for future tense?

Comment: @mcalex There are various possible versions, but what you would normally expect from this and the use of infinitives with auxiliary verbs: (1) *You **will be hanged** for your crimes.* (3) *You **will hang** for your crimes.* (2) *The paintings **will be hung** in the gallery.* (4) *The paintings **will hang** in the gallery.*

Comment: @shoover to be fair, the first sentence about the paintings actually **does** reflect the difference between *hang (v.t.)* and *hang (v.i.)*, and the participle for *hang (v.i.)* **does** seem to be *hung* in ever possible scenario. BUT, this does not tell the whole story of *hang (v.t.)*, as clearly exemplified by the sentences that follow.

Comment: "Salzella shrugged. "We've got to do this properly. Did you know Dr Undershaft was strangled before he was hung?"
"Hanged", said Bucket, without thinking. "Men are hanged. It's dead meat that's hung".
"Indeed?" said Salzella. "I appreciate the information. Well, poor old Undershaft was strangled, apparently. And then he was hung."

Answer (score 7):

If you check the dictionary entry that you quoted, you will see that **hung** is used for suspending things, but **hanged** is not. The entry for killing people states that both **hanged** and **hung** are possible, but it doesn't make it clear that **hanged** is a lot more common.

[This](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he%20was%20hung%2Che%20was%20hanged&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3) Ngram graph shows that, in British English, **hanged** is much more common, and in the 19th century, when Sir Arthur Conan Doyle was writing, it was a lot more common than **hung**.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/hung-or-hanged).

Remember, though, that this is a 21st century representation of a 19th century representation of an imaginary dialogue. The reason that Sherlock corrected this is that the script writer (and possibly also Conan Doyle) decided that he should do it.

Comment: Probably it was a way to illustrate how pedantic and pefectionist Holmes is.

Comment: His last name was just Doyle ;)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings that is true, but in Victorian times, double barreled names (usually mother's maiden name followed by father's name) were very popular, and many people who were not christened with a double barreled name chose to use their last forename as if it were.  Conan Doyle chose to do this, and I think that we should respect his wishes.